# (very) few and negative polarity items

Tags: quantifiers, polarity-items

The negative polarity item *ever* normally occurs with interrogative or negative sentences:

> a. *John has ever been to Japan. (unacceptable)

> b. Has John ever been to Japan? (acceptable)

Now consider the following. Are they okay with *ever*?

> c. Few people have **ever** experienced such an ordeal.

> d. Very few people have **ever** experienced such an ordeal.

> e. A few people have **ever** experienced such an ordeal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Ordeal** is countable, so you must write **such an ordeal.**
2. C and D are otherwise correct. D sounds *slightly* more natural because **very** and **ever** are both used to add emphasis.
3. E is not correct because **a few** does not have negative polarity. It indicates presence, not absence. If I tell my friend that I have **few dollars**, it means we *cannot* go to the pub because I cannot afford to spend them. If I tell my friend I have **a few** dollars, it means we *can* go to the pub, but we will not be able to have many glasses of beer.

Comment: *Few people have **ever** been worshipped as gods* is fine, but so is *Few people have **never** lost their temper.* I think those are both okay because ***few people*** can have both positive *and* negative polarity - it's only when preceded by the indefinite article that ***a few people*** doesn't have negative polarity (because as you say, the defining characteristic is ***non-zero "presence"***, which means it can only have positive polarity). I do like your examples - very accessible and intuitive, I think.

Comment: How about "Only a few people have ever experienced such an ordeal"?

Comment: "Only a few" is a like "very few," so yes that works.